# Mysql - Finding out where the max value comes from

Tags: mysql, max

i have a SELECT statement which returns me the max value from 3 columns in a given interval, but i need to know in which column this max value happens, could anyone help with this? My current code is:

```
$con->prepare("SELECT MAX(GREATEST(L1_RMS,L2_RMS,L3_RMS)) AS maior_valor FROM ELEVA WHERE <conditions>")
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: What do you mean need to know?You want the name of the column returned also?

Comment: I need to know which column (L1_RMS or L2_RMS or L3_RMS) this MAX(GREATEST) comes from. So, yes, the column name also returned would fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c9bb6/5)

```
select  id,  GREATEST(L1_RMS, L2_RMS, L3_RMS) value,
        case GREATEST(L1_RMS, L2_RMS, L3_RMS)
         when L1_RMS then 'L1_RMS'
         when L2_RMS then 'L2_RMS'
         when L3_RMS then 'L3_RMS'
         end columnName
 from table
```

Comment: Really good solution! :) But i'm getting returned here columnName = NULL. Just to check, does this case works with MAX(GREATEST) aswell?

Comment: MAX is superfluous in your case,just remove it.

Comment: But i really need the max value from the rows that result from ur code.

Comment: Why don't you use 2 queries,because MAX will get a single value and that will break the query.

Comment: Yeah, i was just wondering that, and i think that with ur code i'll be able to get it. Thanks a lot!